# Select element from kendoGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

There are lots of elements in database, which are displaying in kendo Grid. Grid loads 50 records from db while user are scrolling.
I want to implement feature that allows user to see the last selected element in grid, when he will leave the page and then returns to page with grid again(selected element id stored in cookies). And the sequence of elements should be the same.
But the problem is that user can choose element, which is not contained in current 50 records in grid and then neither element will be selected.
The question is how to implement that all with kendo grid? Or is it real at all?
Any help appreciates. 
Here's my view code

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RegistryUserDto>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Title(UserResources.NameLabelText).Width(180);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CompanyName).Title(UserResources.CompanyLabelText).Width(187);
        columns.Bound(o => o.RoleNames).Title(UserResources.TypeLabelText).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden();
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable(x => x.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(100)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetUsersList", "Users").Data("GetFilterParameters"))
    )
)
```

And here is controller method:

```cs
public ActionResult GetUsersList(string parameters, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var getUsersRequestViewModel = new GetUsersRequestViewModel();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters))
        getUsersRequestViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetUsersRequestViewModel>(parameters);
    var getUsersRequestDto = new GetRegistryUsersRequestDto()
    {
        Name = getUsersRequestViewModel.Name,
        CompanyId = getUsersRequestViewModel.CompanyId,
        RoleId = getUsersRequestViewModel.RoleId
    };
    var usersList = _usersDomainService.GetRegistryUsers(getUsersRequestDto);

    return Json(usersList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: If the grid is loaded as scrolling, and you want the user to be able to get the last element in the grid without reaching the bottom then there is no way you can pass that element (which isnt even loaded yet) back to the controller as the application doesn't even know it exists. You'll probably need to have a  button somewhere that the user can click that calls a stored procedure to get the last record from the database and return it

Comment: @JamesS not the last record in db, but the last selected record in grid, it can be last record and can be the record in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Observe the Network traffic and the request to the GetUserList. It will have properties such as `sort: page: pageSize:`. When the user makes a selection the id will be on the page, so save those network parameters as well.

On renavigation to the page retrieve the saved page and id.

- Retrieve the data page with `grid.dataSource.page(<saved-page>)`
- Remake selection with `grid.select(grid.table.find('tr[data-id="'+<saved-id>+'"]'))`

Comment: ok, but data-uid changes every time i reload the page, and how i can scroll to the needed page, when amount of pages is more than 50?